# How to use spring-boot-actuator 2.7.3 in a spring-core project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Can I implement Spring Actuator 2.7.3 in my Spring MVC app without adding Spring boot?

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: check here please. https://www.javachinna.com/add-spring-boot-actuator-2-x-support-to-spring-mvc-rest-application-without-using-spring-boot/